# Adding noise to P3DX model

Tags: ros, gazebo, p3dx, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Ros users:

I am trying to add gaussian noise to velocities of P3DX. The model that I am using is from this source https://github.com/RafBerkvens/ua_ros_p3dx
I have modified this part of code:

```
  <!-- ground truth -->
    <gazebo>
        <plugin name="p3d_base_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_p3d.so">
            <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
            <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
            <bodyName>base_link</bodyName>
            <topicName>${ns}/base_pose_ground_truth</topicName>
             <gaussianNoise>0.01</gaussianNoise>
            <frameName>map</frameName>
            <!-- initialize odometry for fake localization -->
            <xyzOffsets>0 0 0</xyzOffsets>
            <rpyOffsets>0 0 0</rpyOffsets>
    <velocityGaussianNoise>10 10 10</velocityGaussianNoise>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>
```

I change the part where it says "gaussiannoise nad velocityGaussianNoise" but it works in the same way.

Does anybody know how i can add gaussian noise to P3DX model??

Thank you so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213774/adding-noise-to-p3dx-model/) by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2015-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Alvaro,

Did you manage to do it? I digged into the [code](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/gazebo_plugins/html/gazebo__ros__p3d_8cpp_source.html#l00326) and normaly, changing the gaussianNoise should do something.

In fact, the value of gaussianNoise is added to the covariance matrix, all along the diagonal, but no effect on the value themselves.

And on top of that, though the noise/covariance are based on a random process (Box Muller transform to be exact), the values never evolve in time even in the covariance matrix.

If we could change the above source code it should be ok, but the source is not in my computer and I don't want to mess around...

Let me know if you found anything,
Quentin

---

Originally posted by [quentin](https://answers.ros.org/users/24914/quentin/) with karma: 123 on 2016-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0